# convert List of List to list float

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

I have a list of list of coordinate with data type of float for example something like this

```
[[106.4372634887695, -6.3303128514375], [106.4372634887695, -6.3299716218919], [106.4376068115234, -6.3299716218919]]
```

and I want to convert it so the inside bracket would be gone and replaced only by comma. and the comma inside the deepest bracket would be replaced too by space

and the final format would be something like

```
((106.4372634887695 -6.3303128514375, 106.4372634887695 -6.3299716218919, 106.4376068115234 -6.3299716218919))
```

Is there a good way to solve this?

I tried to use map and join but i didn't succeeded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: Probably this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you want is not the representation of any type which exists in Python. If you want it as a string, then, turn to string processing:

```
pairs = [[106.4372634887695, -6.3303128514375], [106.4372634887695, -6.3299716218919], [106.4376068115234, -6.3299716218919]]

stringified = ', '.join(' '.join(map(str,pair)) for pair in pairs)

parenthesized = f'(({stringified}))'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten your array by using:

```py
flatten = [elm for bracket in data for elm in bracket]
```

It's like:

```py
arr = []
for bracket in data:
    for x in bracket:
        arr.append(x) #or arr += [x]
```

If you just want to sum brackets, do:

```py
final = [a + b for a,b in arr]#b is -|b|, it's negative, then a+b is the same as 106.xxx - 6.xxx
```

Comment: but how do you remove the comma inside the bracket though? 
from
[106.4372634887695, -6.3303128514375], [106.4372634887695, -6.3299716218919]
to
106.8365478515625 -6.32537841796875, 106.8365478515625 -6.324005126953125

Comment: check your results, there are not same

Comment: sorry, I mean from [106.4372634887695, -6.3303128514375], [106.4372634887695, -6.3299716218919] to  (106.4372634887695 -6.3303128514375 , 106.4372634887695, -6.3299716218919)

Comment: ```finnal = [a + b for a,b in arr]#b is -|b|, it's negativ, then a+b is the same as 106.xxx - 6.xxx```

Comment: sorry again, but the data should be presented as-is because it is a coordinate location, no calculation is needed here, in that case how to approach this problem?